# Magento2 : Add to cart is not working on enable FPC

Tags: addtocart, full-page-cache, magento-2.1.7

On my magento2 store `add to cart` is not working when enabling `FPC`.

`/Checkout/cart/add` ajax returning 302 error on click on add to cart button -

[image]

When FPC disable then all works fine, `/checkout/cart/add` ajax return 200.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you found a solution?